# IIS - HTTP 403.1 Forbidden Error on Website

Tags: iis, asp-classic, permissions

I have copied parts of an old ASP website out into a new website. On my local machine where the code was cleaned up and tested the website works perfectly, however, on the Windows Server 2000 machine it needs to run on I am getting an error:

```
HTTP 403.1 Forbidden: Execute Access Forbidden
Internet Information Services

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Technical Information (for support personnel)


Background:
You have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed.
```

I have tried giving I_USR full control of the local web directory and selecting Scripts & Executables in IIS. All this has not changed anything.

In the end I tried doing an IIS re-install, but that has not solved the problem.

Any ideas where else I can look?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304916) and see if it helps with your problem.

While I do not say that your Windows 2000 server was upgraded from .Net 4, it smells like there is something not registered properly with ASP.